# Authenticated Referrals - how to tell if a user just authenticated

Tags: facebook, authentication

I have a game where I want to track user logins/installs. I need to be able to detect when a user was just redirected to my app from the authenticated referral dialog. Since we cannot specify our own redirect_uri after the user authenticates, nor does Facebook append any sort of flag for canvas apps - is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

> 3 Auth Token Parameter: If Authenticated Referrals is enabled and when a
>   user authorizes your app through the in-line Auth Dialog, we will pass
>   your app the Auth Token in the format specified here. Available
>   formats: URI Fragment: if your app is using client-side
>   authentication, Query String: if your app is using server-side
>   authentication. If your app is a canvas app, we will not use this
>   setting and will use the "signed_request" as the response type
>   automatically.

Based on that information from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/, I would suggest you read the signed_request and see if the auth token is there. If the token is there and that id is already in your data store, you dont log is as a new app install.  If the token is there and that id is not already in your data store, then you can add the user to your list of app users in your data store and track it as a new install.

Comment: Hi DMCS, since this will be for a library that will be distributed, I'd like to avoid using any sort of local data store/database. Previously, we would append flags to the redirect_uri of the auth dialog to indicate the user just authed. This isn't 100% reliable (as people can modify the url, etc.) but it was the best solution given our requirements. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Nope, sorry.  Hope you find something, otherwise you'll have to implement a data store. (My original answer assumed you were collecting/tracking the installs).

Comment: The problem with this method is that you would need to check to see if the user is in the database on every page load of every page just to catch the 0.001% of page requests that come from an authenticated referral. As far as I see there is no way to do this in an app. Facebook does append ?code=... for websites that use Facebook authenticated referrals. I don't see why they can't do something similar for a canvas app.